# select next row in mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a select SQL query:

```
select * from table where sequence = '6'
```

i want to be able to get the next row however it may not be sequence 7, as this may not exist.

if the next row is sequence 9 how would i select it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Order by `sequence` and use `limit` to define an offset of `1`

```
select * from your_table
where sequence >= 6
order by sequence
limit 1, 1
```

Comment: LIMIT 1,1 would skip the first... wait... oh, you're selecting WHERE >= 6.

Comment: Yes, because the next record may also be `sequence = 6`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help...

```
select * from table where sequence > '6' order by sequence ASC limit 0,1
```

Comment: This will never select the row, if sequense is 6. It can also be 6.

Comment: sorry but the questioner have write it differently... he want the one AFTER the six... so i do no need to select the value 6 in sequence.. yes.. i missed the limit part... will be limit 0,1

Comment: No, he said after the code example "...as this may not exist."

Comment: If you want to quote, quote it completely "i want to be able to get the next row however it may not be sequence 7, as this may not exist." so the 7th can not exists. is how i read it ;)

Comment: Well that is not related to this.

Comment: But is related to my reply. Is you that have other in mind maybe =)